# stuck with loading jquery on the bottom of my page in php

Tags: php, jquery

I'm fighting with this module since yesterday. Documentation is poor or there is something I am doing wrong.

This is the link from the original html files.
www.bestbuildpc.org/Html5_Player/index.html

This is the link for the documentation

www.bestbuildpc.org/Html5_Player/readme/index.html

I converted to a module in order to work in Ravennuke(based on phpnuke)

This is the link where the module is not loading properly.

http://www.bestbuildpc.org/modules.php?name=HTML5_Player

```
<?php

if (!defined('MODULE_FILE')) die('You can\'t access this file directly...');
if (!defined('PHP_EOL')) define('PHP_EOL', strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS,0,3) == 'WIN') ? "\r\n" : "\n");

require_once 'mainfile.php';
$module_name = basename(dirname(__FILE__));
$pagetitle = '- ' . $module_name . '';

$index = 0;
if (!defined('INDEX_FILE')) define('INDEX_FILE', true); // Set to FALSE to hide right blocks
if (defined('INDEX_FILE') AND INDEX_FILE === true) {
    // auto set right blocks for pre patch 3.1 compatibility
    $index = 1;
}
$ThemeSel = get_theme(true);
$html5player = 'themes/' . $ThemeSel . '/css/normalize.css';
if (file_exists($html5player)) {
    define('RN_MODULE_CSS', 'normalize.css');
} else {

    $html5player = 'modules/' . $module_name . '/css/normalize.css';

addCSSToHead($html5player, 'file');
addCSSToHead('modules/' . $module_name . '/mediaelement/mediaelementplayer.min.css', 'file');

//  addJSToHead('modules/' . $module_name . '/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js', 'file');//I have another version loading
//echo '<script type="text/javascript">!window.jQuery && document.write(\'<script src="modules/HTML5_Player/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"><\/script>\')</script>' . PHP_EOL;
//echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.jQuery && document.write(\'<script src="includes/jquery/jquery.js"><\/script>\')</script>' . PHP_EOL;
  addJSToBody('modules/' . $module_name . '/mediaelement/mediaelement-and-player.min.js', 'file');
  addJSToBody('modules/' . $module_name . '/js/jquery-ui-1.11.1.sortable.min.js', 'file');
  addJSToBody('modules/' . $module_name . '/js/jquery.ui.touch-punch-improved.js', 'file');
  addJSToBody('modules/' . $module_name . '/js/jquery.hammer-full.min.js', 'file');
  addJSToBody('modules/' . $module_name . '/js/perfect-scrollbar-with-mousewheel.min.js', 'file');
  addJSToBody('modules/' . $module_name . '/js/jquery.vimuse.min.js', 'file');
  $JStoHeadHTML = '
<script type="text/javascript">' . PHP_EOL
//        . '$(window).load(function(){' . PHP_EOL
        . '$(document).ready(function(){' . PHP_EOL
         . '$(\'#player\').vimuse()({' . PHP_EOL
         . 'mediaType: \'audio\',' . PHP_EOL
         . 'showPlaylistOnLoad: true,' . PHP_EOL
         . 'autoplay: true,' . PHP_EOL
         . 'shuffle: true,' . PHP_EOL
         . 'showPlaylistOnLoad: true,' . PHP_EOL
         . 'playlistProgress: true,' . PHP_EOL
         . 'showFileTypeIcons: true,' . PHP_EOL
         . 'showDeleteButtons: true,' . PHP_EOL
         . 'showItemDuration: true,' . PHP_EOL
         . 'enablePlaylistSort: true,' . PHP_EOL
         . 'showAudioDetails: true,' . PHP_EOL
         . 'showAudioCover: true,' . PHP_EOL
         . 'showAuxControls: true,' . PHP_EOL
         . 'playlistProgress: true,' . PHP_EOL
         . 'stopPlaybackOnPageHide: false,' . PHP_EOL
         . 'showDownloadLinks: false,' . PHP_EOL
         . 'scanMP3Folder: true,' . PHP_EOL
         . 'mp3Folder: \'media/audio\'' . PHP_EOL
         . '});' . PHP_EOL
         . '});' . PHP_EOL
         . '</script>' . PHP_EOL;
    addJSToBody($JStoHeadHTML, 'inline');
}

include_once 'header.php';

OpenTable();
echo '<div class="text-center">' , PHP_EOL
    , '<div class="header-content">' , PHP_EOL
    , '<h1>HTML5 Media Player</h1>' , PHP_EOL
    , '</div></div>' , PHP_EOL
    , '<div class="main">' , PHP_EOL
    , '<div id="player">' , PHP_EOL
    , '</div></div>' , PHP_EOL;
CloseTable();
include_once 'footer.php';
```

What am I doing wroong. The module is not working. I need example from the same files. I've been reading and testing lots of ways to load jquery but I don't get any more idea of what is going on. it will be nice if someone take a look at it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What output you get?

Comment: Yes what does you HTML source look like? What needs to change from HTML source in order to make it work (i.e. are the file paths wrong, are the script just not showing up in source, etc.)?

Comment: I just edited the file with the output. all path from the scripts are correct.